# Perform action on Notification when it comes under notification tray

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to perform an action(save Unique id coming with notification, in a text file) if notification comes on Notification tray but not viewed?

Answer (score 0):

Technically application delegates for notification trigger when you tap on notification in tray(open or view). you can not do anything on notification receive until any user-action on it. But when the app is in foreground `applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification` automatically triggered by ios on notification receive, at that point you can do what you want. But not when your app is in background or not running.